# Convert/Replace multiple shapes (Ellipse into Polygon)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I am familiar with the `Convert to Shape` effect which lets me replace Ellipses by Retangles.

However I would like to convert ellipses into triangles (3 sides polygons). Is there a way to do that?

Ps: I have multiple ellipses I want to convert at once without changing the size and position.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that Illustrator has a quick way of doing this. It could definitely be scripted. But InDesign has that functionality. A quick fix could be to copy the ellipses from Illustrator to InDesign, change them to triangles and copy them back to Illustrator.

Comment: Okay! Thank you for your comment! I'll study there approaches :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do so using the following scrip:  [findAndReplaceGraphic_centered](http://kelsocartography.com/scripts/#nvkelso)